# How to detect overlap from randomly generated prefabs

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, instantiation, overlapping

I have a working script which randomly generates:

PosX, PosY, ScaleX and ScaleY

I have my randomly generated prefabs into parallel arrays. From that randomly resized and positioned cubes are generated. However since it is randomly generated how can i detect there is a overlap by code ? And when there is an overlap how can i delete it ?

I need help writing the code. Ive tried using raycasting and OnTriggerEnter but im too confused as to how to do it. Ive also seen using the

```
Physics.CheckCapsule
Physics.CapsuleCastAll
Physics.CheckSphere
Bounds.Intersect
```

But i don't know how to do it.

I don't know how to use Physics.OverlapSphere on arrays.
What am i supposed to do.

```
void Detect_Collision_Two(int i) {
    bool isOverLapped = false;

    Collider[] platformsInRange = Physics.OverlapSphere(platformPrefabPosition[i], scaleX[i]/2);
    foreach(Collider col in platformsInRange) {
        if(col.gameObject == platformPrefab) {
            continue;
        }
        if 
    }


}
```

**Edit**

Attempt
These are the attempt i have tried to do using the math methods. Which checks the center position and takes into consideration of the width and height of the platform. Then using that information to compare with other platforms.

The second method is using the OverlapSphere , but i have no idea how to implement that.
Please help

```
void Platform_Position_Scale_Generator(int i) {

    posX[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posY[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posZ[i] = 0;

    scaleX[i] = Random.Range(minScaleRange, maxScaleRange + 1);
    scaleY[i] = 1;
    scaleZ[i] = 1;

}

void Platform_Generator(int i) {

    platformPrefabPosition[i].x = posX[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].y = posY[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].z = posZ[i];

    Instantiate(platformPrefab, platformPrefabPosition[i], Quaternion.identity);
    platformPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX[i], 1, 1);


}

// Error with this
void Detect_Collision(int i) {

    for(int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
        for(int s = f + 1; s < i; s++) {
            bool xOverlap = (posX[s] > posX[f] && posX[s] < posX[f] + scaleX[i]) || (posX[f] > posX[s] && posX[f] < posX[s] + scaleX[i]);
            bool yOverlap = (posY[s] > posY[f] && posY[s] < posY[f] + scaleY[i]) || (posY[f] > posY[s] && posY[f] < posY[s] + scaleY[i]);

            if(xOverlap && yOverlap) {
                Debug.Log("xOverlap: " + xOverlap + " yOverlap: " + yOverlap);
            }
            else {
                //Debug.Log("xOverlap: " + xOverlap + " yOverlap: " + yOverlap);
            }
        }
    }

}

void Detect_Collision_Two(int i) {
    bool isOverLapped = false;

    Collider[] platformsInRange = Physics.OverlapSphere(platformPrefabPosition[i], scaleX[i]/2);
    foreach(Collider col in platformsInRange) {
        if(col.gameObject == platformPrefab) {
            continue;
        }
        if 
    }


}
```

Comment: How is the question too broad ?

Comment: Because it's not a specific programming problem, instead a task to accomplish. [so] is not a coding service. Please take a __[tour]__. __Attempt the problem__ first, then post __specific problems__ - Any question which requires answerers to write code from scratch or write a book to explain something are too broad. If you can reword it to fit [guidelines for reopening your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please do so.

Comment: Is the above not clear enough ?

Comment: How can i ask so its not that broad ?

Comment: __Attempt the problem__ first, then post __specific problems__.

Comment: Ive edited it , hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you need to make an **overlapSphere** with your object position center as its center and **bounds extent magnitude** as its **radius** and check for all the **colliders** in this boundry if thier bounds **intersect** with new object bounds

```
 bool isOverlapped = false;
 Bounds bounds = renderer.bounds;
 Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, bounds.extents.magnitude);
 foreach(Collider col in cols) {
     if (col.gameObject == gameObject) {
         continue; 
     }
     if (bounds.Intersects(col.gameObject.renderer.bounds)) {
         isOverlapped = true;
         break;
     }
 }
```

after this you can use the **isOverlapped** bool to **destroy** your object like this

```
 if(isOverlapped)
         Destroy (gameObject);
```

Comment: So is this a script for the original platform prefab ?
Because what i did is that , i made a gameobject in the Hierarchy which generates the platforms.
Sorry , i don't know how to implement this onto my game.
Could you go into more detail ?
Thanks . .

Comment: you should use this on every object you want to create to make sure it is not colliding with anything when it is being created

Comment: Since i recorded everything in an array and its parallel.
What do you need to change in your code to suit my needs ?

Comment: use it when you want to spawn aomething

Comment: So . . what is the radius of the Sphere ?

Comment: it is renderers bounds extent the description is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html)

Comment: The console is giving me a problem when i run it.
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

Comment: I think you don't get what im doing.
I have a gameobject which has no components except a script.
And what that script does it generate random position and scales, which in turn instantiate the blocks.
And as for the code you gave me. I don't know how to implement it in my script.
Because you're referencing the overlapSphere and all kinds of stuff. But i think its only referencing the script that generates the block.
But im supposed to reference the prefabs.
How can i do that ?